# Validator error when POSTing. Creating a RESTful API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

I am implementing an API for a task management and has two endpoints users and tasks. The schema design for the 'users' looks like:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { 
        type:String,
        required: true
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },

    pendingTasks: [String],

    dateCreated: { 
        type: Date, 
        default: Date.now }
});
```

and my POST looks like

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){
    var userPost = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email
    }
    user.create(userPost, function(err, users){
        if(err) {
            res.status(500).send({
                message:err,
                data: []
            });
        } else {
            res.status(201).send({
                message: 'OK',
                data: users
            });
        }
    });
});
```

When I try to test my POST on postman with a dummy data by doing

[image]

I am getting a "ValidatorError" and it gives me a message that says "User validation failed: email: Path 'email' is required, name: Path: 'name' is required.

[image]

This seems weird because I just passed in dummy data 'name' and 'email'.

I am new to creating RESTful API so I might be making a stupid mistake, but I really don't get it.

Comment: From the information your provided, I have 2 suggestion: (1) Debug to check what is in "req.body.email". (2) Make sure to install "body-parser" moudle, this article can help you understand what does this module actually do for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306569/what-does-body-parser-do-with-express

Comment: Thanks again. I am pretty sure body-parser is installed because I've used it with my previous schema. How do I debug to check what is in the req.body.email in the postman? Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also deployed an app in my local PC and debug, if you select **raw** as your body type, the **email** property will NOT be exist in the **req.body** object.

To solve this problem in Postman, you have to select **x-www-form-urlencoded** and input your data as key-value pairs:
[image]